# IEPY Package - Installation Error - Syntax Error - Python

Tags: python, nlp, syntax-error

I have some troubles in interpreting the documentation (http://iepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) commands of the Python IEPY package for Natural Language Processing. The first step to work with IEPY is to create an "instance" (as a non-programmer I have little idea what is it all about). They also provide the command to do it:

```
iepy --create <project_name>
```

My problem is that when I type the exact sentence into my command line, I get a "syntax error". I suppose that I do not follow some coding conventions and misinterpret what I should really type. Would be glad to hear what I do wrong.

Another source of the problem could be an improper installation of some of the additional libraries required for IEPY. After trying to install IEPY using 
`pip install iepy`, I got a big fat error message after "collecting django-angular-0.7.8". The command line reports an "Exception", gives a reference to the line, where it happens and describes the source of an error (this is how I interpret the output at least). Which is:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position
>   4: invalid start byte

Here is the screenshot (cannot use copy-paste in my command line)

[Installation of IEPY: The Error Message While Installing IEPY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4uKw.png)

P.S. It looks that the documentation in general is Linux-users oriented while I am using Windows 8.1. Is it the source of my troubles?

Comment: Omit the `<` `>` characters?

Comment: Does not work. In the case the command line says: "iepy" is not an internal or external command (it's a loosy translation of mine from Russian in English).

Comment: So is the directory where `iepy` lives in your %path%?

Comment: I used the command pip install iepy. I, therefore, suggest that iepy was installed somewhere into my python folder, which lives in my %path%

But it looks like iepy could not install properly. I got an error during installation of one of the Django packages.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to copy and paste the error messages that you get, both when running the command and when trying to install (not just the error, but some context, like which command did you run and some lines around the error message). That will allow to provide more usuful answers

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error while installing the IEPY package.